# Calculate subtotal with special condition

Tags: sql, presto, trino, subtotal

| id | flow | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IN | 100 | 2023-08-01 |
| 2 | OUT | 100 | 2023-08-02 |
| 3 | IN | 100 | 2023-08-03 |
| 4 | OUT | 100 | 2023-08-04 |
| 5 | OUT | 100 | 2023-08-05 |

In a table like above, I want to sum all OUT transactions which take place after every IN transaction. The desired outcome should look like below:

| id | flow | amount | date | out_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IN | 100 | 2023-08-01 | 100 |
| 3 | IN | 100 | 2023-08-03 | 200 |

How could this be achieved?

Comment: What is the desired output if you have an ID 6 with an IN transaction, but nothing else after that? Also, can you have two consecutive IN transactions?

Comment: If there's an ID 6 with an IN transaction, then I would like to see another row in the output for this with out_amount 0.  And yes, we could get consecutive IN transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Presto then you can follow gaps-and-islands approach (based on provided data I would use `id` as ordering field, but for actual you might need/want to use `date`):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(id, flow, amount, date) as (
    values (1,  'IN',   100,    '2023-08-01'),
    (2, 'OUT',  100,    '2023-08-02'),
    (3, 'IN',   100,    '2023-08-03'),
    (4, 'OUT',  100,    '2023-08-04'),
    (5, 'OUT',  100,    '2023-08-05'),
    (6, 'IN',   100,    '2023-08-11')
)

-- query
select min(id) id,
    min_by(flow, id) flow,
    min_by(amount, id) amount,
    min_by(date, id) date,
    sum(if(flow = 'OUT', amount)) out
from (select *,
             count_if(flow = 'IN') over (order by id) as grp
      from dataset)
group by grp
order by id;
```

Output:

| id | flow | amount | date | out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IN | 100 | 2023-08-01 | 100 |
| 3 | IN | 100 | 2023-08-03 | 200 |
| 6 | IN | 100 | 2023-08-11 | NULL |

For Trino you can also use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
-- query
SELECT *
FROM dataset MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
     ORDER BY id
     MEASURES
         A.id as id,
         A.flow as flow,
         A.amount as amount,
         A.date as date,
         SUM(B.amount) AS out
     ONE ROW PER MATCH
     AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
     PATTERN (A B*)
     DEFINE
            A AS flow = 'IN',
            B AS flow = 'OUT'
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard gaps and islands. Tag with the number of IN rows and then use grouping.

```
with data as (
    select *,
        count(case when flow = 'IN' then 1 end) over (order by date) as grp
    from T
)
select
    min(id) as id,
    'IN' as flow,
    min(case when flow = 'IN' then amount end) as amount,
    min(date) as date,
    sum(case when flow = 'OUT' then amount end) as out_amount
from data
group by grp
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a subquery with a `cte`:

```
with cte as (
   select t.*, (select sum(t1.flow != t.flow and t1.id < t.id) 
   from transactions t1) r from transactions t
)
select t2.id, t2.flow, t2.amount, t2.date, t1.amount out_amount 
from (select t.r, sum(t.amount) amount from cte t where t.flow = 'OUT' group by t.r) t1
join cte t2 on t2.flow = 'IN' and t2.r = t1.r - 1
```